Splunk search with a variable for unique result count
My query is :
"Call made for " "%2F1234" | timechart span=1d count by APP_NAME

Where 1234 is lets say a team ID. Using this query, I get the calls made for this team over a period of time.
What I want is instead of manually searching for each Team ID's incoming calls, give a variable there for Team ID and get a count for the calls made to it grouped by unique Team IDs such that I get a pie chart for all request counts for each Team ID.

Extract the team ID from the event then count the events by ID.
index=foo "Call made for " "%2F*" 
```Extract the team ID```
| rex "%2F(?<team>\d+)"
| stats count by team

Then click on the Visualization tab and change the chart type to Pie.
